# Why this reinterpret_cast fails in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, alias, reinterpret-cast

I have some code(see below), and curiously it compiles fine when I run the code through gcc, but when I open up the same file in Visual Studio 2017, I get a compiler error to the tune of:

```
Error   C2440   'reinterpret_cast': cannot convert from '::size_t' to 'Alias'
```

Here's a minimal example that you can try if you want. Just hit "new project", and select the C++ windows console application, insert this code, and try to compile in the default x86-debug mode:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstddef>

typedef std::size_t Alias;

Alias makeAlias(std::size_t n)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<Alias>(n);
}

int main()
{
    std::size_t x = 1;
    Alias t = makeAlias(x);
    return 0;
}
```

Oddly enough if you change the return statement to this slightly more convoluted variant, it indeed compiles, so it seems like Visual Studio decided to allow `reinterpret_cast` only for pointer types:

```
return *(reinterpret_cast<Alias*>(&n));
```

This strikes me as a strange decision by Visual Studio, because, according to [cpp reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

> Unlike static_cast, but like const_cast, the reinterpret_cast expression does not compile to any CPU instructions. It is purely a compiler directive which instructs the compiler to treat the sequence of bits (object representation) of expression as if it had the type new_type.

So it would seem, at least to me, that if I attempt to `reinterpret_cast` between two types that occupy memory in the exact same way, then reinterpret_cast is really what is called for. After all, I am, as the name suggests, "reinterpreting" the same bit pattern to another type.

I realize that `reinterpret_cast` is mainly targeted toward converting between pointer types, but I don't see why I should be barred from using it in situations like this. In a sort of "use the right tool for the right job" sense, wouldn't it make more sense to allow programmers to use `reinterpret_cast` for its intended purpose, rather than forcing them to use `static_cast` when that's not necessary (not to mention needlessly burning a few clock cycles in the process)?

Is there some sort of danger in allowing `reinterpret_cast` between aliased types that would cause Visual Studio to disallow this? `Reinterpret_cast` can definitely be dangerous when used incorrectly, but I can't see why it would have to fail if used properly (unless of course I'm missing something in the definition of "proper" use in this case).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I've gone ahead and edited the question

Comment: You left off the 2nd half of the error message: "note: Conversion is a valid standard conversion, which can be performed implicitly or by use of static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast".

Comment: FWIW this has little to do with decisions, or CPU instructions, or occupying memory. It's about bugs & semantics (or lack thereof)

Comment: By the way that edited MCVE is excellent - you can probably go ahead and remove the old version as it's just getting in the way

Comment: Great that's better. In general, good job with this question and with the followup (sadly very rare for low rep users). You will go far here :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I accidentally edited my previous comment instead of adding a new comment. Let me try again:  I'm struggling to see any use case for allowing reinterpret cast to the same type for integral types, and I also don't see where OP is going with it (since the code would be come incorrect if `makeAlias` were changed to use other non-pointer/reference types than exactly what it has)

Comment: @M.M: Well, whether there's a use case for it is a different matter entirely (personally I see zero purpose in prohibiting it, and you could get some benefit when the operands are some `T1` and `T2` in a template).

Comment: I suppose it could be used as a way to generate a compilation error if `Alias` were changed to something other than `size_t` or a typedef for the same type

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> `[C++14: 5.2.10/2]:` The `reinterpret_cast` operator shall not cast away constness (5.2.11). An expression of integral, enumeration, pointer, or pointer-to-member type can be explicitly converted to its own type; such a cast yields the value of its operand.

Since `std::size_t` is an integral type, and `Alias` *is* `std::size_t`, I'd say that this is an amusing Visual Studio bug.

Comment: It basically comes to this: `reinterpret_cast<int>(1);` which throws error in VS

Comment: @KillzoneKid: Exactly.

Comment: Wait, I'm confused. Is this a VS bug? Replicates in VS 2019. Does the standard say reinterpret_cast<int>(1) should not compile? How else should one reinterpret a bit sequence?